# Write a unit test for service : AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, karma-jasmine

I have few questions with to write a proper unit test for a service using `jasmine` as framework and `karma` as test runner.

here is what i implemented in **example-service.js**:

```
export default class ExampleService {
constructor($resource, $http) {
'ngInject';

this.$resource = $resource;
this.$http = $http;
}

exampleMethodOne() {
//some code lines
}

exampleMethodTwo() {
//some code lines 
}

}
ExampleService.selector = 'myExampleService';
```

Here what i wrote in my test **example-service.test.js**

```
let myExampleService, $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(() => {
    angular
      .module('exampleApp', [])
      .service(ExampleService.selector, ExampleService);
    angular.mock.module('exampleApp');
  });

  beforeEach(inject((_myExampleService_, _$httpBackend_) => {
    myExampleService = _myExampleService_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  }));
```

i have imported the `angular-mocks.js` and `example-service.js`

when i try this scenario the console will throw a `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- myExampleService`
 error.

please help me to solve this.

Comment: Please, update the question with actual error message because it was truncated. Even if the answer solves your case, this may be helpful to future readers.

Comment: @estus updated the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$resource` requires angular-resource.js and respective module to be loaded:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    angular
      .module('exampleApp', ['ngResource'])
      .service(ExampleService.selector, ExampleService);
    angular.mock.module('exampleApp');
  });
```

Comment: thank you adding ngResource and importing the angular-resource.js will solved the issue thanks a lot @estus :)

Comment: can i know if we additionally pass $urlMatcherFactory to constructor what should changes need to be made?

Comment: Depends on what $urlMatcherFactory is.